# Commenting on old answers to ask for clarification: is it rude?

Tags: discussion

I often find myself landing on a stackoverflow question that has been answered when I web search a problem I'm trying to solve. Sometimes the answer is almost perfect, with one thing I don't understand. For example, I just searched how to do something in bash, found an [answer that worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939038/how-do-you-run-a-command-for-each-line-of-a-file/13941223), but couldn't get it to work in a Makefile.

In cases like this, when the answer is usually at least a few years old, is leaving a comment asking the OP to clarify something okay? Is it rude to necro-ping like that?

Comment: If it was unclear to you, odds are the answer was unclear to someone else. I see no harm in asking for clarification. And the OP responded, seems like a win-win for everyone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First check on the answerer's profile whether he's still active on the site. If he is, feel free to ask a clarification (I know I wouldn't mind that at all). Feedback on answers is one of the purposes of the comment system after all.

If he's not active anymore, you'd be best served by asking a new question. Make sure the new question links to the answer, and **explicitly** states which part you didn't understand. Usual question guidelines apply, so make sure your question is high-quality.

If you ask a new question about an inactive user's answer, you should also leave a comment on that answer linking back to your question, to guide other users that may have the same issue as you.

Comment: thanks, this seems like the best course of action (and pretty much what i did). it's worth noting that (if i'm not mistaken) comments get deleted after a while, so leaving a link to the new question is only helpful in the short term.

Comment: No, the comments aren't deleted automatically. But they're considered second-class citizens, and AFAIK mods tend to delete them more eagerly than answers when they're flagged.